# setContentView screen area differences

Tags: android

I don't understand the different behavior of the function `setContentView`.

The activity is in fullscreen mode so without status bar and system bottom bar.

The call of the function `setContentView` from the `onCreate` load the layout as if there was still the system bottom bar with the result of the empty area (the layout zero coordinate are on top of this area). Screenshot of a empty layout with only a bar on bottom: [image: empty layout]

**Instead** if the same function `setContentView` is called from another place (e.g. a function called by a button) the layout are correctly load with the same size of the screen. Screenshot: [image: correct layout]

I use just the:

```
setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
```

I've tried a separated function but if is called from the inside of the `onCreate` the result is the same, also put the `setContentView` as first place of the `onCreate`. No matter if the layout is the same or another.

I don't understand where is the problem, it shows up on Android 5.1 phisical device and 9 emulated device, so I think is a code problem (latest version of IDE and SDK).

---

Edit: added code for fullscreen mode.
The position of the `setContentView` not matter if is the first, before or after the other lines etc, I've tried.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initClass.hideStatusBar(this);
    initClass.setFullscreen(getWindow().getDecorView());
    setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
    ...
}
```

```
public static void hideStatusBar(Activity activity){
    activity.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    activity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}

public static void setFullscreen(View decorView){
    int ui_Options = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(ui_Options);
}
```

---

Edit: I've tried into a new clean project of an empty app and all things works as expected so the problem is specific of that project. I start an investigation...

Comment: How are you hiding the bottom navigation ? And when ? Before starting the activity or after the setContentView ?

Comment: Added the code for the fullscreen mode. The order of calls not change the result

Comment: Have you already tried to place the calls to the `initClass` just before `super.onCreate()`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to set fullscreen parameters as first operation obtaining the same result. (I've also tried all combination of the order of these lines just in case...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was a single line in the parameters of the layout that I load that include the layout with the activity content. The line was:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```